# Issue converting NSData Object into NSDictionary

Tags: json, swift, nsdata

I'm trying to extract information from a JSON file.  Is it possible there is something wrong with the JSON output?  There seems to be some strange encoding. It's from a blog.

> **JSON**:

```
[{
  "title": "A visit to McSorley\u0027s Old Ale House",
  "subtitle": "",
  "summary": "\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;McSorley\u0026#39;s Ale House is Manhattan\u0026#39;s oldest pub\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;"
}]
```

I successfully create `NSData` Object, but `NSJSONSerialization` fails, see the code:

```
func parseJSON(jsonString: String) -> [String: AnyObject]? {
    guard let data: NSData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        else { return nil }

    do {
        let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
        return dictionary

    } catch {
        print("JSON Error: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: At top level your JSON seems to be a NSArray, with only one item a dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine the problem is your JSON file, try with another JSON file for example, the following one:

```
var json = "{\"xyz \":[{\"title\": \"\",\"subtitle\": \"\",\"summary\": \"\"}]}"

func parseJSON(jsonString: String) -> [String: AnyObject]? {

   guard let data: NSData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       else { return nil }

   do {
       let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
       return dictionary

   } catch {
       print("JSON Error: \(error)")
       return nil
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
Optional(["xyz": (
    {
    subtitle = "";
    summary = "";
    title = "";
}
)])
```

You're missing the key for the JSON dictionary, if for that I put it some key in the beginning of the JSON to make it works. Nevertheless I strongly recommend you use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to parse JSON files in an excellent way.

> **Removing the HTML String**

```
extension String {

   /**
   Strip the HTML tags for the string passed.

   - parameter code: String to strip HTML.

   - returns: The new string without HTML tags.
   */
   func stripHtmlTags() -> String {
       return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<[^>]+>", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
   }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Victor, thanks for the reply, but I'm still struggling with this.  As you suggested, it does appear to be an issue with the JSON.  I have a better sense of the issue though.  I'm pulling blog posts from an MS SQL database.  The posts are HTML encoded.  When I create the NSData object the html is getting converted to UTF8 which has characters that cause an error when I try to access the value in that key.  Do you have any idea how I can remove the HTML before I create the NSData object?  Thanks!

Comment: @MartinMuldoon I've the same issue a long time ago and I remove the HTML string with Regular Expressions. See my update answer